# type script android interface

Tags: javascript, android, typescript

So I am developing for a couple a devices and basically need to do a check to determine the device. For example

```
// Android being js interface
if(Android) return setupAndroid()
else if(exampleDevice) return method()
etc
```

If you have done this before you know my problem. If you open this app in a browser not on android it will crash because android does not exist. I have to do it this way and since ive started I do not want to stop till I figure out a way to handle this. I have tried creating a ts interface and did not work. I need a way to say this Android interface does exist only in the android layer. So this type of check is going to happen for every device. The number of devices does not matter. What matters is how do you avoid errors of non existing variables.

Comment: Is `Android` an object you've created that you've installed in the DOM specifically in your Android client? Why wouldn't you specify it to TypeScript as a `declare` in all cases and then check its existence at runtime as you have?

Comment: `Android` will not exist unless unless your project executed some code to create it. The best solution here is to make sure that variable always exists, but it may be `true`/`false` depending on the platform. Either way it's not really possible to answer that question without understanding where that variable is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're exposing a specific Android interface via [`WebView.addJavascriptInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)), but as far as TypeScript is concerned you should [`declare` the global variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) as if it always exists. If you want to be extra safe, mark it as possibly `undefined` so you always have to check its existence before use.

```
interface AndroidType {
  field1: string;
  method1(): void;
}
declare var Android: AndroidType | undefined;

if (Android) {
  Android.field1 = "foo";
  Android.method1();
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIgCZQPbAwFQE8AHFAbwFgAoZZGYCAGwwEYAuZAZzClAHMA3NVoBbCGAAW2VgAoAlBwBuuDEKoBfahggJGcKCkX60mHHg7osKoqWQAfZAFdMEeiAirq1YDGQzLZhhyyJQ0JlZ4AHT0TKzIALzIAEQw2NhJarQBKpFiktIs8mqaVEA)